# Tap event for a UIView with alpha set going to underlying button

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

When loading data from server, we mask our UI using a UIView like the following sample code:

```
let loadingView = UIView()
loadingView.tag = 9999
loadingView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
loadingView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.4);

controller.view.addSubview(loadingView)
```

As you can see this loadingView takes the entire width and height of the controller and practically masks the screen. Having alpha means underlying content is translucently visible. We remove this view from controller after data has loaded like this:

```
for view in controller.view.subviews
{
    if view.tag == 9999
    {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

However we are seeing strange issue where-in if a user keeps tapping a UIButton on the controller while the loadingView is shown, tap on the button is invoked as many times after the loadingView has been removed from the controller. In other words, our action for UIButton tap gets invoked as many times as you tapped it while the loadingView was shown.

Are we doing something wrong? How can we prevent the tap on UIButton from being invoked while the loadingView is shown?

Comment: Turn on user interaction for `loadingView`.

Answer (score 0):

You should doable user interaction on the loading view.

```
loadingViee.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

As you said the loading view is on all over the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can Ignore touch of your screen during the loading view Once finished loading view you can continue Interaction as like below.

```
UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
```